# Сохраняется ли прописная буква у глагола, если исходное существительное в непривычном значении пишется с прописной?

Tags: семантика, прописная-строчная, глаголы, прилагательные, существительные

Есть вымышленная вселенная, в которой живут Ваятели — магические пришельцы, обладающие энергией Ваяния — создание практически любых материальных объектов из этой энергии (то есть Ваятели и Ваяние — пишутся с прописной, чтобы показать, что эти слова употреблены в непривычном значении — это название расы и её деятельности). Так вот, как написать глагол, они **в**аяют или **В**аяют? Другими словами, сохраняется ли прописная буква у глагола, как у существительного, в этом случае? В прилагательных вроде бы нет: **в**аятельская доктрина, **в**аятельские корабли... А вот с глаголом подзапутался, какое правило тут работает или же практика письма?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (15.12.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310011)):

> Род пришельцев нужно писать со строчной буквы аналогично названиям народностей (ср.: *эвенки*, *коми*, *буряты*), так же нужно писать и глагол. Непривычное значение не является основанием для написания слова с заглавной буквы. При этом существительное от глагола ваять может записываться со строчной, но возможно написание и с заглавной, если ему приписывается особо высокий смысл.